# asyncio and GET: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM

Tags: python, python-requests, get, python-asyncio

### Update

My asyncio powered GET requestor is giving me issues today, but only for certain workItem requests that it makes.

It is not a particular workItem that is causing the issue. I can retrieve a single workItem and then run the same function again and get rejected with the error:

`Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

The line that triggers the error is: `workItem = await resp.json()` in this function:

```
async def getWorkItem(self, session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
        workItem = await resp.json()  <----------------- the problem
        workItem = pd.json_normalize(workItem['value'])
        workItem.columns = workItem.columns.str.replace(
            'fields.', '', regex=False)
        return workItem
```

How might I try to solve this decoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `BOM` before decode json, a minimal example:

**test.py:**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # async with session.get('http://127.0.0.1:9989/data.json') as resp:
        async with session.get('http://127.0.0.1:9989/with_bom.json') as resp:
            raw_text = await resp.text()
            text_without_bom = raw_text.encode().decode('utf-8-sig')
            work_items = json.loads(text_without_bom)
            print(type(work_items))
            print(work_items)

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Explanation:**

1. Use `text()` to replace `json()` to get the raw text.
2. Remove `BOM` using `utf-8-sig` decode.
3. Use `json.loads()` to transform `str` to `dict`.

Above code works both for response with BOM or without BOM.

Comment: Thank you very much -- this solved it and made it more robust! I am still unclear why I could pull the workItem sometimes, but every `n` times, I would get the BOM error.